# Linq and returning types

Tags: c#, linq

My GUI is calling a service project that does some linq work, and returns data to my GUI. However, I am battling with the return type of the method. After some reading, I have this as my method:

```
public static IEnumerable GetDetailedAccounts()
 {
 IEnumerable accounts =(from a in Db.accounts
                        join i in Db.financial_institution on  
                            a.financial_institution.financial_institution_id
                               equals i.financial_institution_id
                        join acct in Db.z_account_type on a.z_account_type.account_type_id 
                               equals acct.account_type_id
                        orderby i.name
                        select new 
                             {
                              account_id = a.account_id, 
                              name = i.name, 
                              description = acct.description
                              });
            return accounts;
}
```

However, my caller is battling a bit. I think I am screwing up the return type, or not handling the caller well, but it's not working as I'd hoped.

This is how I am attempting to call the method from my GUI.

```
IEnumerable accounts = Data.AccountService.GetDetailedAccounts();

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Accounts:");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

foreach (var acc in accounts)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00} {1}", acc.account_id, acc.name + " " + acc.description));
  }

int accountid = WaitForKey();
```

However, my foreach, and the acc - isn't working. acc doesn't know about the name, description and id that I setup in the method. Am I at least close to being right?

Comment: No, same project, but I want to split them into separate projects. So, assume they are separate for now.

Comment: your service is in remote? and is better to use `var` instead of this argument type.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should maybe rather build a shared class lib, which has 'transfer objects'. So in my method, I get the data, and load them into a List<TransferObject>, and return that. Then both the project that does the linq, and the GUI will know the type?

Comment: Please provide your exact code, you can't iterate over IEenumerable and fetch account.

Comment: @Saeed I believe that's what he's saying is the problem.  He didn't explicitly say it but I assume his problem is that it won't compile and he's wondering why.

Comment: Sorry guys - that is indeed the problems. I have provided all the code. So, I was showing what wasn't working. The error is that it can't resolve acc.account_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@BrokenGlass is correct that the root of the issue is that you're using an anonymous type.  That results in you using the non-generic version of IEnumerable which doesn't know what type the objects are.

Rather than using `dynamic` though (which requires .NET 4.0 which may or may not be an issue for you), I would recommend creating an actual `Account` class.

That way you can return an `IEnumerable<Account>` instead of just `IEnumerable`.  Then you'll be able to use the properties since it knows that it's an Account.

Once you create the Account class your method then becomes:

```
public static IEnumerable<Account> GetDetailedAccounts()
{
    IEnumerable<Account> accounts = (from a in Db.accounts
                    join i in Db.financial_institution on a.financial_institution.financial_institution_id
                        equals i.financial_institution_id
                    join acct in Db.z_account_type on a.z_account_type.account_type_id equals
                        acct.account_type_id
                    orderby i.name
                    select new Account {account_id = a.account_id, name = i.name, description = acct.description});
    return accounts;

}
```

Then the calling code can remain the same.

I thought I should point out that `var` doesn't work the way you probably think it does.  The type of the variable is still determined compile-time, which means (for the most part) it's just a shortcut.  Your example would be identical to if you had used `object` instead of `var` because `IEnumerable` can only contain `object`.

If you're working in .NET I'd recommend follow .NET naming conventions though so `AccountId` instead of `account_id` but that won't affect whether it works or not.

Comment: Nice, thanks. So Data Transfer Objects would be a suitable solution here? Maybe declare a class in a shared library, called 'AccountDetail', with the properties I need (id, name and description). And then return List<AccountDetail>? Both the GUI project and the data service project have reference to the shared lib, so the AccountDetail object is 'known' on both sides?

Comment: @cdotlister Correct.  The `dynamic` solution could work (I'm not very familiar with the feature but I assume BrokenGlass knows what he's talking about) but creating a real class has the benefit of the compiler catching some errors if you decided to remove/rename a property.  You also get Intellisense support since it's a real class.

Comment: I think there is a free vs2010 addin that can refactor anon classes into concrete classes, but I'm not in the office and can't look up the name. Something to look up maybe, if you need to do this often.

Comment: Agreed, in practice you don't want to use dynamic typing if you can get away with static typing - for some reason I was under the impression cdotlister didn't want to create classes for his anon types, that's why I suggested a different approach.

Comment: I've created Data Transfer objects (I think). Is that what is meant by static typing?

Comment: @cdotlister static typing means that the compiler knows the type of the object it's working with and will catch errors when you compile rather than when the error happens at runtime.  In the `dynamic` approach that BrokenGlass showed, if for example you had mistyped `account_id` the compiler wouldn't show an error because it doesn't know what type `acc` is.  Dynamic typing was added in .NET 4.0 because it is sometimes useful (as a contrived example if `GetDetailedAccounts` was someone else's code that you couldn't modify) and to support other languages that are dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an anonymous type that the user of the method has no way of casting back to. An easy way out (besides reflection or creating a class) would be using [**dynamic**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), since you know the properties you want to access are there:

**Example:** (very made up I admit)

```
public static IEnumerable GetAccounts()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
           .Select(x => new { Id = x, Name = "herbert" });
}

//...
foreach (dynamic account in GetAccounts())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}", 
                      account.Id, 
                      account.Name));
}
```

Back to your code that would mean just changing the calling code:

```
foreach (dynamic acc in accounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00} {1}", acc.account_id, acc.name + " " + acc.description));
}
```

Comment: It's not true, the `OP` doesn't provide exact code or he can't compile it, how you can iterate IEnumerable and fetch account? I mean this line: `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00} {1}", acc.account_id, acc.name + " " + acc.description))` it can't be compiled.

Comment: That's correct guys  -it's not compiling, as acc.account_id can't be resolved. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Davy8 is correct, and also **creating a custom BusinessObject (AccountDetail)** would be a better solution for long term external library life cycle (if you are using this AccountDetail alot in your logic/Code), since you can customize it as you want

having a transfer class (AccountDetail) easily allows you to bind back to some UI in design time and make the concept of your project a more bit clear, you can also re-use it more often

```
public class AccountDetail
{
public string AccountID{get;set;}
public string AccountName {get;set;}
public string AccountDescription {get;set}

public AccountDetail(){}
}
```

so Query is:

```
public static List<AccountDetail> GetDetailedAccounts()
{
  return (from a in Db.accounts
         join i in Db.financial_institution on a.financial_institution.financial_institution_id
equals i.financial_institution_id
join acct in Db.z_account_type on a.z_account_type.account_type_id equals
acct.account_type_id
orderby i.name
select new AccountDetail 
{   AccountID = a.account_id, 
     AccountName= i.name, 
      AccountDescription= acct.description}

}).ToList();
```